# Group by to show unique fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
SELECT Volunteer.VolunteerID, Volunteer.LastName, Volunteer.FirstName, Observations.VolunteerID, Roost.RoostID, Roost.UTME, Roost.UTMN, Roost.DecimalDegrees, Observations.Date, Location.LocationName, Location.Address, Town.Town
FROM (((Volunteer INNER JOIN Observations ON Volunteer.[VolunteerID]= Observations.[VolunteeriD])
LEFT JOIN Roost ON Roost.[RoostID]= Observations.[RoostID])
LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.[LocationID]= Roost.[LocationID])
LEFT JOIN Town ON Location.[TownID]= Town.[TownID]
ORDER BY Volunteer.LastName, Volunteer.FirstName;
```

Currently a part of my table looks like this:

```
    Observations.VolunteerID | Observations.LocationID | Date

    Bob                      | Main St                 | 2015-01-01  
    Bob                      | Main St                 | 2015-02-02
    Sally                    | Fox St                  | 2015-02-02
    Dave                     | Long St                 | 2015-02-02
    Dave                     | Taylor St               | 2015-02-05
    Lindsay                  | New St                  | 2015-02-01
    Lindsay                  | New St                  | 2015-02-08
    Lindsay                  | Ray St                  | 2015-02-10
    Lindsay                  | Main St                 | 2015-02-25
    Lindsay                  | Taylor St               | 2015-02-31
```

However, I want to add a `GROUP BY` statement (I think) that is grouped by *VolunteerID* and *LocationID* so that I get the following output. I want to know each location the volunteers have been at, and if they visited the same location multiple times, I would like to see the most recent date. How would I incorporate that into my original code?

```
    Observations.VolunteerID | Observations.LocationID | Date
    Bob                      | Main St                 | 2015-02-02
    Sally                    | Fox St                  | 2015-02-02
    Dave                     | Long St                 | 2015-02-02
    Dave                     | Taylor St               | 2015-02-05
    Lindsay                  | New St                  | 2015-02-08
    Lindsay                  | Ray St                  | 2015-02-10
    Lindsay                  | Main St                 | 2015-02-25
    Lindsay                  | Taylor St               | 2015-02-31
```

---

Updated code, but still getting syntax error (missing operator in query expression 'Volunteer.FirstName GROUP BY Observations.VolunteerID'.

```
SELECT Volunteer.VolunteerID, Volunteer.LastName, Volunteer.FirstName, Observations.VolunteerID, Roost.RoostID, Roost.UTME, Roost.UTMN, Roost.DecimalDegrees, Max([Observations.Date]), Location.LocationName, Location.Address, Town.Town
FROM (((Volunteer INNER JOIN Observations ON Volunteer.[VolunteerID]= Observations.[VolunteeriD])
LEFT JOIN Roost ON Roost.[RoostID]= Observations.[RoostID])
LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.[LocationID]= Roost.[LocationID])
LEFT JOIN Town ON Location.[TownID]= Town.[TownID]
ORDER BY Volunteer.LastName, Volunteer.FirstName
GROUP BY Observations.VolunteerID, Observations.LocationID;
```

Comment: Your updated query is wrong. See my answer again. You have to aggregate every column that is not a part of `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Put the `ORDER BY` clause after the `GROUP BY`.  I suspect that will resolve your current error.  And then you will face a *different* error due to the issue @ConsiderMe described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `ORDER BY` clause after the `GROUP BY`.

Change `Max([Observations.Date])` to `Max(Observations.Date)`

Add any field expression from the `SELECT` list which is not an aggregate expression to your `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT
    Volunteer.VolunteerID,
    Volunteer.LastName,
    Volunteer.FirstName,
    Observations.VolunteerID,
    Roost.RoostID,
    Roost.UTME,
    Roost.UTMN,
    Roost.DecimalDegrees,
    Max(Observations.Date) AS latest_observation,
    Location.LocationName,
    Location.Address,
    Town.Town
FROM (((Volunteer INNER JOIN Observations ON Volunteer.[VolunteerID]= Observations.[VolunteeriD])
    LEFT JOIN Roost ON Roost.[RoostID]= Observations.[RoostID])
    LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.[LocationID]= Roost.[LocationID])
    LEFT JOIN Town ON Location.[TownID]= Town.[TownID]
GROUP BY
    Volunteer.VolunteerID,
    Volunteer.LastName,
    Volunteer.FirstName,
    Observations.VolunteerID,
    Roost.RoostID,
    Roost.UTME,
    Roost.UTMN,
    Roost.DecimalDegrees,
    Location.LocationName,
    Location.Address,
    Town.Town
ORDER BY Volunteer.LastName, Volunteer.FirstName;
```

However I am uncertain whether that grouping will be suitable.  In the question, you wanted to group on *Observations.VolunteerID* and *Observations.LocationID*.  This larger `GROUP BY` may not give you the same result.

If that is the case, you can use an aggregate function for a `SELECT` field and then remove that field from the `GROUP BY`.  For example ...

```sql
SELECT Max(Volunteer.LastName)
```

Assuming *LastName* is always the same for a given *VolunteerID*, `Max(Volunteer.LastName)` will give you that same value.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. HansUp, your code worked perfectly...still figuring out organization so will try Consider Me's code when I'm a bit more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 3):

`max` with the `group by` clause seems to be enough:

```
select Observations.VolunteerID, Observations.LocationID, max([Date])
from <...>
group by Observations.VolunteerID, Observations.LocationID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and an aggregate function `MAX()` on date.

```
SELECT VolunteerID, LocationID, MAX(Date)
FROM(
SELECT 
  Volunteer.VolunteerID, 
  Volunteer.LastName, 
  Volunteer.FirstName, 
  Observations.VolunteerID, 
  Roost.RoostID, 
  Roost.UTME, 
  Roost.UTMN, 
  Roost.DecimalDegrees, 
  Observations.Date, 
  Location.LocationName, 
  Location.Address, 
  Town.Town
FROM 
  (((Volunteer 
  INNER JOIN Observations ON Volunteer.[VolunteerID]= Observations.[VolunteeriD])
  LEFT JOIN Roost ON Roost.[RoostID]= Observations.[RoostID])
  LEFT JOIN Location ON Location.[LocationID]= Roost.[LocationID])
  LEFT JOIN Town ON Location.[TownID]= Town.[TownID]
ORDER BY Volunteer.LastName, Volunteer.FirstName
) foo
GROUP BY VolunteerID, LocationID
```

Comment: Thank you for your help...I'm getting closer, however still coming up with an error:

Comment: What is the error? Update your question please, don't post this in comment.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Volunteer.FirstName GROUP BY Observations.VolunteerID'.

Comment: Please post the code you are executing and the error in your question.

Comment: Updated my question with the newer code from peoples' suggestions.